# How to get back dataframe from the encoded Julia ModelMatrix Object?

Tags: matrix, dataframe, julia, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have Dataframe which has categorical data which is Dummy encoded as shown below:

[image: Dataframe Dummy]

```
>pool!(data1csv, [:Country, :Purchased])
mm = ModelMatrix(ModelFrame(@formula(Purchased ~ Country + Age + Salary), data1csv, contrasts = Dict(:Purchased => DummyCoding(), :Country => DummyCoding())))
```

[image: Dataframe Dummy]

The `Country` and `Purchased` features have been Dummy encoded. After I apply normalization feature to Salary and Age, how can I infer which country does the observation below, belong to?

[image: Dataframe Dummy]

Is there any way to achieve this? Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you post an example someone can paste to their REPL

Comment: Yeah, super difficult to read with those screenshots! I'm sure someone will help if you post the code & output using the "code sample" function at the top of the text box.

Comment: Please do not cross-post simultaneously in two different forums. At the very least, if you don't get a reply in one place, give a link to the other post so that people don't waste their time replying twice. Previous post is [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dummy-encoding-one-hot-encoding-from-pooleddataarray/4167/6).

Comment: The dictionary from values to original strings in the pooled variables is stored in the field `pool` of the PooledDataArray. There is a need to undo the dummy encoding. It adds up to: `data1csv[:country].pool[Vector{Int}(1.0+mm.m[:,1:3]*[0.0 1.0 2.0])]`. Note the `3` in `1:3` and `0.0 1.0 2.0` is because of the number of countries, other fields may have a different number of dummy variables

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard will keep in might next time i post it.

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat will certainly avoid cross post.

Comment: @DanGetz thank you for the explanation with code.